# R - Tabulate character vectors - customized output

Tags: r

I'd like to tabulate the values of some small character vectors, and have the tabulation results appended to the string. For the reproducible example below, my desired output would look something like this:

```
  states                 responsible
1     KS             Joe(2);Suzie(3)
2     MO                      Bob(4)
3     CO    Suzie(1);Bob(2);Ralph(3)
4     NE                      Joe(1)
5     MT           Suzie(3);Ralph(1)
```

Here's the example data:

```
states <- c("KS", "MO", "CO", "NE", "MT")
responsible <- list(c("Joe", "Joe", "Suzie", "Suzie", "Suzie"), c("Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob"), c("Suzie", "Bob", "Ralph", "Ralph", "Bob", "Ralph"), "Joe", c("Suzie", "Ralph", "Suzie", "Suzie"))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(states, responsible))

#Tabulating using table()
resp.tab <- lapply(responsible, table)

#Is there a way I can do tabulation without converting to factors?
# OR
#Is there a way to access the factor label and value, then paste them together?
```

Comment: `table` also works with `character` vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.   Create a `data.table` by replicating the 'states' with the `lengths` of 'responsible' and `unlist`ing the 'responsible'.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(states= rep(states, lengths(responsible)),
                 responsible=unlist(responsible))
```

Grouped by 'states', and 'responsible', we get the frequency (`.N`), then grouped by 'states', we `paste` the 'responsible' and 'N' column and `collapse` the rows belongs to the same 'states'.

```
dt1[,  .N, .(states, responsible)
  ][,  .(responsible = paste(paste0(responsible, 
                   "(", N, ")"), collapse=";")) ,.(states)]
#  states              responsible
#1:     KS          Joe(2);Suzie(3)
#2:     MO                   Bob(4)
#3:     CO Suzie(1);Bob(2);Ralph(3)
#4:     NE                   Joe(1)
#5:     MT        Suzie(3);Ralph(1)
```

---

Or a similar option is with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tbl_df(dt1) %>% 
   group_by(states, responsible) %>% 
   tally() %>% 
   unite(responsible, responsible, n, sep="(") %>% 
   group_by(states) %>%
   summarise(responsible = paste(paste0(responsible, ")"), collapse=";"))
```